# Is there a way to update a flatlist when there's a change in firestore database?

Tags: reactjs, firebase, react-native, google-cloud-firestore, react-native-elements

I have a list that displays user profiles, names, and the last message sent. Pretty much in a way a regular messaging app displays users. What I'm trying to do is have the list update when there's a change from the users being displayed. I tried having it update on render but with resetting states, it goes onto an infinite loop which brought up my read operations to 10k in a matter of seconds. So far I have it update with pull to refresh but I want it to update live. I'm not sure if I would need to use cloud functions (e.g. *onCreate*) or a timer to not quickly go over my quota limit.

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import { View, FlatList } from "react-native";
import { ListItem } from "react-native-elements";
import fireStoreDB from "../database/FirestoreDB";

export default class Home extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      usersInfo: [],
      refreshing: false
    };
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    this.LoadUsers();
  }

  LoadUsers = () => {
    fireStoreDB
      .getAllUsersExceptCurrent()
      .then(
        users =>
          Promise.all(
            users.map(
              ({ id, username, avatar }) =>
                fireStoreDB
                  .getUserLastMessage(fireStoreDB.getUID, id)
                  .then(message => ({ id, username, avatar, message }))
            )
          )
      )
      .then(users => {
        this.setState({
          usersInfo: users.filter(x => typeof x.avatar !== "undefined"),
          refreshing: false
        });
      });
  };

  renderItem = ({ item }) => (
    <ListItem
      onPress={() => {
        this.props.navigation.navigate("Chat", {
          userTo: item.id,
          UserToUsername: item.username,
          LoadUsers: this.LoadUsers
        });
      }}
      title={item.username}
      subtitle={item.message}
      leftAvatar={{ source: { uri: item.avatar } }}
      bottomDivider
      chevron
    />
  );

  render() {
    return (
      <View>
        <FlatList
          data={this.state.usersInfo}
          renderItem={this.renderItem}
          keyExtractor={item => item.id}
          refreshing={this.state.refreshing}
          onRefresh={() => {
            this.setState({ refreshing: true });
            this.LoadUsers();
          }}
        />
      </View>
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: You can use real-time event on your Firestone collection

Comment: @Hurobaki Thanks, I got it to work using the onSnapshot listener.

Comment: @CLUTCHER, I am glad that you were able to find the solution on your issue. Please post it as answer and accept it as solution as this will help other community members that are looking for the same issue.

Comment: @AndreiCusnir I've posted my solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved it by doing this.

```
  async componentDidMount() {
    await Font.loadAsync({
      "open-sans-semi-bold": require("../assets/fonts/OpenSans-SemiBold.ttf"),
      Roboto: require("../node_modules/native-base/Fonts/Roboto.ttf"),
      Roboto_medium: require("../node_modules/native-base/Fonts/Roboto_medium.ttf"),
      ...Ionicons.font
    });

    this.unsubscribeMsg = fireStoreDB.lastMsgListener(this.LoadUsers);
    this.unsubscribeUser = fireStoreDB.userProfileListener(this.LoadUsers);
    this.setState({ isReady: true });
  }

  componentWillUnmount() {
    this.unsubscribeUser();
    this.unsubscribeMsg();
  }

  lastMsgListener = loadUsersCallback => {
    return firebase
      .firestore()
      .collectionGroup("chats")
      .onSnapshot(() => {
        loadUsersCallback();
      });
  };

  userProfileListener = loadUsersCallback => {
    return firebase
      .firestore()
      .collection("users")
      .onSnapshot(() => {
        loadUsersCallback();
      });
  };
```

Comment: CLUTCHER thank you very much for providing the full solution to the issue. Please also accept it as solution, as soon as you can. This will give more visibility to the question and answer for the other members of the community.

Comment: where is LoadUsers method?